# Manually lose focus from TextField select component, Material UI & React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a select input which I create by using [TextField](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/) component from Material-UI lib. I need to manually lose focus after some option been selected. I tried to use a reference to the TextField using 'inputRef' prop, which works great but when I try to fire blur() function on this.selectInput.current like I did here but without MaterialUI lib.

```js
class Select extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
     selected: ''
    }
    
    this.inputRef = React.createRef();
    this.onChangeHandler = this.onChangeHandler.bind(this)
  }
  
  onChangeHandler(e){
  
 this.inputRef.current.blur()

   this.setState({
     selected: e.target.value
    })
  }
  
  render() {
   const {selected} = this.state;
  
    return (
      <select value={selected}
          onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
          ref={this.inputRef}>
        <option value=''>Please select</option>
        <option value='1'>One</option>
        <option value='2'>Two</option>
      </select>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Select />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

I got an error that blur() function does not exist. I understand that Material UI used custom el. to create UI and I target just a div or whatever. So the question is it another way to get the exact behavior (lose focus on the select event) when using TextField component or maybe I did something wrong?

Material UI v1.3.1 | React v16.4.2

Answer (score 6):

Try to define onClose method with the following body:

```
onClose() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.activeElement.blur();
    }, 0);
}
```

and then pass this method to onClose prop of the select element.

Comment: anyone know why this only works in a `setTimeout`?

Comment: I think it works, because you have to lose the focus on next iteration of JS event loop which actually is done by using "setTimeout".

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue with blur event in react material-ui Select component

**Below solution worked for me.**

```
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
<Select
...
onClose={()=>{
    setTimeout(() => {
        setOpen(false)
        handleSubmit();
    }, 0);
}}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way, it's just rerender it with a new key:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';
import { nanoid } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
...
const [inputKey, setInputKey] = useState<string>(nanoid());
...
// You need to blur here, for example.
const someFunc = () => {
    setInputKey(nanoid())
}
...
<TextField select key={inputKey} />
```